# CakePHP 3 - How to do document useImmutable() method in bootstrap.php

Tags: php, cakephp, phpdoc, scrutinizer

We use scrutinizer to inspect our code. Here is one "bug" related to phpdoc:

```
<?php
 *
 * @method \Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType[] useImmutable()
 */
Type::build('time')->useImmutable();
```

**Error message:**

> The method **useImmutable()** does not exist on **Cake\Database\Type**. It
>   seems like you code against a sub-type of Cake\Database\Type such as
>   **Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable and typehint it:

```
/** @var \Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType $time */
$time = Type::build('time');
$time->useImmutable();
```